# インターフェースを用いた簡単な画面出力(Laravel4.2)

Tags: laravel

簡単なサンプルソースを参考に画面出力をしようと思ってますが、
下記のエラーがでているところです。

> Argument 1 passed to {closure}() must be an instance of App\Services\Messenger\Messenger, string given

クロージャの第一引数がオブジェクト型ではないということで、
おこられているようなのですが、
どこを修正すればよいかご教授願えないでしょうか。

■コントローラー

●Messenger.php

```
<?php // app/Services/Messenger/Messenger.php

namespace app\Services\Messenger;

interface Messenger {
    public function send($message);
}
```

●MailMessenger.php

```
<?php  // app/Services/Messenger/MailMessenger.php

namespace app\Services\Messenger;

class MailMessenger implements Messenger {

    public function send($message) {
        // ここで、メールでメッセージを送る

        return "メールで $message を送りました。";
    }
}
```

●BikeMessenger.php

```
<?php  // app/Services/Messenger/BikeMessenger.php

namespace app\Services\Messenger;

class BikeMessenger implements Messenger {

    public function send($message) {
        // ここで、バイクに乗ってメッセージを届ける

        return "バイク便で $message を届けました。";
    }
}
```

■ルーター

```
// app/Http/routes.php

use app\Services\Messenger\Messenger;

Route::get('send_message/{message}', function(Messenger $messenger, $message){
    return $messenger->send($message);
});
```

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のサイトを参考にされたのだと思いますが・・・。

[サービスプロバイダーの作成 | ララ帳](https://laravel10.wordpress.com/2015/04/23/%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%93%E3%82%B9%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90/)

このサイトの記事は **Laravel 5** を対象にしています。

あなたが試そうとしたコードは `function(Messenger $messenger, $message)` の第一引数に適切なインスタンスが挿入されることを期待していますが、これは Laravel 5.0 で導入されたメソッドインジェクションという機能によるものです。 Laravel 4.2 ではコンストラクタの引数にしか自動挿入は行われません。

参考 [Laravel 5 はこう変わる！ メソッドインジェクションとFormRequest編 - localdisk](http://localdisk.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/10/01/173347)

Comment: Ｌａｒａｖｅｌ５の環境下で同じ実装をおこなったらうまく表示されました。どうもありがとうございました！